# Kubernetes cluster nodes running out of inodes in /tmp

Tags: kubernetes, inode

Is there a recommended minimum size (or minimum number of inodes) for the `/tmp` file system (partition) on Kubernetes cluster nodes?

What I am experiencing (on a bare-metal Kubernetes 1.16.3 cluster) is that cluster nodes hit 100% inodes used (according to `df -i`). This has some negative effects (as one would expect; e.g. `kubectl exec ... bash` into pods on concerned nodes leads to "no space left on device") but `kubectl get nodes` (strangely) still reports these nodes as "Ready". The `/tmp` file systems involved are relatively small, i.e. 2G (121920 inodes) and 524M (35120 inodes) respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recommended minimum size for kubernetes. The defaults are good for most cases but is you are creating e.g. many of empty files you might eventually run out of inodes. If you need more you need to manually adjust its number.

Comment: I'm not aware that any of my workloads would create excessive numbers of short-lived files in `/tmp`, so I am still a bit puzzled on why the cluster hits on these limits.

Comment: So I found the culprit now: I was a script started via the `collectd` Exec plugin, which did not delete a temporary file when it failed (because of obsolete credentials). I.e. this was caused neither by the Kubernetes cluster nor by any of its workloads.